# Rolling sum of 2 sample KS test results

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, combining-p-values, moving-window

In order to compare two lists of samples from 'before-treatment' and 'after-treatment', I am doing a two sample KS test using the ks_2samp function from Python's scipy.stats package which gives me the D and p-value statistics. Now I want to do this on a rolling basis. I periodically receive new samples and I want to find a way to reuse the KS statistics calculated from the previous set of samples.

E.g. if one set of before-treatment samples are in x and after-treatment in y then:

> x = [1,1,1,1]
>
> y = [2,2,2,1,1,1]
>
> D, p_value = ks_2samp(x, y)

Output is:

> D = 0.5, p_value = 0.43531018975534286

In next set of samples:

> x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
>
> y = [2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]
>
> D, p_value = ks_2samp(x, y)

Output is:

> D = 0.5, p_value = 0.14848228822491449

Note that for a given x and y, the number of 'before' samples in x and 'after' samples in y can differ. Also note that, the samples in x and y are from independent set of experiments.

Now I want to somehow combine the D and p_values from both of these separate ks test runs and get some idea of the overall result. Should I just take the mean or is there some other way that makes more sense? I don't have much knowledge of statistics so apologies if this is a very trivial question.

Comment: There are a number of ways of combining $p$-values although I do not know whether they are available out of the box in python. Try searching for Fisher's method and Stouffer's method plus python and see if that helps. It is not that difficult to program yourself if nobody has done it.

Comment: And for combining the D statistic output by each KS run, will taking the maximum of the D's be correct?

Comment: I would not try to combine the D statistics. What scientific question would that answer? They might both be large for very different reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this one does not go unanswered I repeat here material from my comments. It is perfectly possible to combine the $p$-values using any of the standard methods. For the two values quoted in the question using four of the most common methods we get.

`eponym       p
Tippett   0.27478
Fisher    0.24157 
Edgington 0.17035
Stouffer  0.19685`

I know of no way of combining Kolmogorov Smirnov statistics and I do not see what scientific question that would answer.

Comment: *It is perfectly possible to combine the -values using any of the standard methods.* – Actually, you cannot. See [my answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/567747/36423) as to why.

Answer (score 2):

The KS test only has a limited number of possible *p* values, in particular for small sample sizes. Standard methods for combining *p* values, however, are based on the assumption that *p* values are uniformly distributed on (0,1] under the null hypothesis. Applying them to results of the KS test with a small sample size will usually considerably overestimate the *p* value.

I wrote a [Python package](https://combine-p-values-discrete.readthedocs.io) that addresses this problem, however, like other answerers and commentors I see no reasonable application to combine *p* values of the KS test, which is why it is not straightforwardly supported and we need to do a bit of work yourself determining all possible *p* values under the null hypothesis.

The following Python script combines your *p* values:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
from combine_pvalues_discrete import CTR, combine

x1 = [1,1,1,1]
y1 = [2,2,2,1,1,1]
x2 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
y2 = [2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1]

def ones_and_twos(template,number_of_twos):
    result = np.ones_like(template)
    result[:number_of_twos] = 2
    return result

def ks_ctr(x,y):
    total_twos = sum(np.hstack((x,y))==2)
    p = ks_2samp(x,y).pvalue
    
    possible_ps = [
            ks_2samp(
                    ones_and_twos( x, twos_in_x ),
                    ones_and_twos( y, total_twos-twos_in_x ),
                ).pvalue
            for twos_in_x in range(total_twos+1)
        ]
    
    return CTR(p,possible_ps)

ctrs = [ ks_ctr(x,y) for x,y in [(x1,y1),(x2,y2)] ]

for method in ["fisher","mudholkar_george","edgington","stouffer","tippett"]:
    print( method, combine(ctrs,method=method) )
```

You get:

- Fisher: 0.17
- Mudholkar–George: 0.13
- Edgington: 0.11
- Stouffer: 0.11
- Tippett 0.25